# Нарисовать круг на гугл карте в пикселях

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как нарисовать на гугл карте кружок, чтобы размер задавался в пикселях и этот кружок не изменялся в размерах при изменении масштаба карты?
Есть вот такой код, рисует круг в координатах, но этот круг изменяется при увеличении или уменьшении масштаба карты.

```
mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(0, 0))
            .radius(5000)
            .strokeWidth(2f)
            .strokeColor(Color.BLACK)
            .fillColor(Color.GREEN));
```

Если никаких решений нет, то как хотя бы привязать параметр "radius" к масштабу карты "mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom", может по какой формуле, чтобы размеры нарисованного круга оставались неизменными при изменении масштаба карты.

Просто хотел нарисовать точки, и соединить их линиями.. Линии между точками рисуются не сложно из листа координат, но как добавить везде кружки, чтобы получился маршрут из отрезков, не понятно..

Answer (score 1):

Если хочешь фиксированный круг, то нужно рисовать Polygon или LineString (если круг полый).
Круг рисуется по точкам. Чем больше точек, тем плавней круг.
Пример круга из LineString https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/circleExample.kml

Для нахождения координат точек на границах окружности используй формулу:

```
lat_p = lat_c + radius * cos(az * pi / 180) / (earth_radius * pi / 180)

lon_p = lon_c + radius * sin(az * pi / 180) / cos(lat_c * pi / 180) / (earth_radius * pi / 180)
```

- lat_p, lon_p - координаты искомой точки.
- lat_c, lon_c - координаты центра круга.
- radius - радиус окружности в метрах.
- earth_radius = 6371000 метров.
- az - азимут точки относительно центра, где 0 - это направление на север, 180 - это направление на юг. Значения от 0 до 360.

Comment: Что-то сложновато как-то, а примерчик нельзя, как вокруг координаты 0,0 нарисовать круг фиксированного размера? Нагуглить не могу ничего похожего..

Comment: @Alex455
Итоговый kml в качестве примера я вложил в ответ. Общий алгоритм: 1. Определиться сколько точек использовать для построения круга. Например 20. 2. Определить азимут для каждой из точек. По сути для этого надо посчитать шаг, разделив 360 на количество точек. Т.е. точка1 - азимут 0, точка2 - азимут 18, точка 3 - азимут 36 и т.д. 3. Найти по формулам координаты каждой точки. 4. Использовать эти координаты для построения полигона или LineString.